# How to get the customer id if user is logged in , in volusion platform

Tags: javascript, cookies, volusion

I want to get the customerid to  do some custom code in volusion.
Please help me if there is any way so that I can fetch the customerid.
I can see in cookie there is a cookie named "CustomerID" but I am unable to decrypt it .

Answer (score 0):

I put this in the jquery .ready() function...

```js
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/v1/users/current",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
   
    firstName = json.data.firstName;
    lastName = json.data.lastName;
    email = json.data.email;
    id = json.data.id;
 
      alert (firstName +  " " + lastName +  " " + email + " " + id + " ") ;
      //return true;
    },
            error: function(e){
            //alert('error '+e.responseText);
         }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Volusion frontend API:

**www.yoursite.com** /api/v1/users

This endpoint will return the logged in user as a JSON.

Comment: your link is not working. it keeps saying Page Not found.